Error fetching version 2.2346.52 from remote FetchError
Error fetching version 2.2346.52 from remote FetchError: request to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wppconnect-team/wa-version/main/html/2.2412.54.html failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND raw.githubusercontent.com
at ClientRequest. (/Users/abc/Documents/Tech_Journey/projects/habait/chatbot/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1501:11)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:518:28)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:495:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:518:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
type: 'system',
errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
code: 'ENOTFOUND'
}
/Users/abc/Documents/Tech_Journey/projects/habait/chatbot/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/FrameManager.js:156
? new Error(${response.errorText} at ${url})
^
Error: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED at https://web.whatsapp.com/
at navigate (/Users/abc/Documents/Tech_Journey/projects/habait/chatbot/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/FrameManager.js:156:23)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async FrameManager.navigateFrame (/Users/abc/Documents/Tech_Journey/projects/habait/chatbot/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/FrameManager.js:131:21)
at async Frame.goto (/Users/abc/Documents/Tech_Journey/projects/habait/chatbot/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/FrameManager.js:512:16)
at async Page.goto (/Users/abc/Documents/Tech_Journey/projects/habait/chatbot/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:1167:16)
at async Client.initialize (/Users/abc/Documents/Tech_Journey/projects/habait/chatbot/node_modules/whatsapp-web.js/src/Client.js:124:9)
Node.js v20.11.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
